# send terminal output to channel (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

i want to make a ping request to a IP then output it in a message from a discord bot

*example*

```
import discord
import os

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
os.system('ping XX.XX.XX.XX')
```

i want the output from **XX.XX.XX.XX** to be sent in a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this like this:

```
from subprocess import run
import discord

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
   x = run("ping XX.XX.XX.XX", capture_output=True).stdout
   await ctx.send(x)
```

Comment: How do i add this to a embed?

Comment: Just find a tutorial on youtube and i assure you, you will find the answer.